# Split tab-bar into sections

Tags: google-chrome, browser-tabs

I have searched far and wide to find an add-on/extension which will allow me to split the area of Chrome where the tabs are stored into different sections.

I will give you an example: I have some music / video tabs which need very little space and can be clustered since I touch them rarely. The section where I am researching stuff must be big and the section where I am storing research material which is worth reading doesn't need to be big again.

I am basically looking for anything that will let me add sections and set their size / priority.

So far I have no luck finding anything.

Edit: The pin tab option is the only thing I've figured might come close to the functionality I am looking for, but I would prefer it to be more organised.

Answer (score 1):

[Tabs Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tabs-outliner/eggkanocgddhmamlbiijnphhppkpkmkl) or some similar extensions may be a little overkill, but will do if you haven't found more fitting way for you.

Using several windows is also a good idea, if your workflow setup allows it.